# Multiply text values and display result

Tags: javascript

i am using below three fields need to `multiply` the Word Count Values through `PHP`. ANy Help ? Code as --  `1` have to `select` the first `dropdown` from here..

```
<select name="sp" id="sp">
<option value="" selected>Please Select...</option>
<option value="Editing">Editing</option>
<option value="Writing">Writing</option>
</select>
```

Then i have a text box in which the number would be provide,like word 100 200 300, as

```
<input type="text" name="Word_Count" id="Word_Count" size="10">
```

and third field would be where the price would be calculated on behalf on word from above row (100 200 300 word), as

```
<input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="" readonly="" size="20">
```

Now if the user will select the `Editing` from `select` box, the price would be calculated as `100 x 0.02, 200 x 0.02, 300 x 0.02` like and the user will select the `Writing`, the price would be calculated at `100 x 0.04, 200 x 0.04, 300 x 0.04`.

HOw can i make the sense to get the output more efficiently ? Any help ?

Comment: Could you provide the jsfiddle for this

Comment: I have no idea where you're stuck. Can you link to your website, show what the actual output is and tell us what you expected?

Comment: @MartinHohenberg Why did you remove the PHP tag? The fact that this problem could also be solved in other languages doesn't mean the OP could use such solutions!

Comment: @kritikaGupta: i have updated the answer. Please check it

Comment: @MartinHohenberg No. This is about a specific problem encountered when making a PHP program. Solutions in other languages simply won't do! If you are programming in C and post here with a problem, do you want to hear solutions in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many complication that you will have to handle.
1) Check that the string entered in Word_Count is number. (Never trust user input. Apply validation techniques)

2) call a javascript function on Onkeyup event of Word_Count.
`<input type="text" name="Word_Count" id="Word_Count" size="10" onkeyup="return somefunction()">`

I have shown you, how to call a function by mentioning it in element. You can also bing jquery function on pageload. Better check-out official documentation if you want it that way.

Html select

```
<select name="sp" id="sp">
<option value="" selected>Please Select...</option>
<option value="0.02">Editing</option>
<option value="0.04">Writing</option>
</select>
```

Changed the value of options.

javascript/jquery function

```
function somefunction(){
    //take value of Word_Count in one variable
    var valWC = $("#Word_Count").val()

    //take value of Word_Count in one variable
    var valDP = $("#sp").val()

    //sumd will hold the product of two numbers
    var sumd = 0;

    //apply validation technique

    //multiply both values valWC and valDP
    //sumd will have the product
    sumd=Number(valWC)*Number(valDP);

    //show it in third box
    $("#price").val(sumd);
}
```

Comment: how could i `multiply` the `values` ? Like if i have `100` `word` in my text box i need to multiply it with `100x.02` if the user has selected `Editing`

Comment: `@ bhavik`, Thankyoi, but how can i put the values in `javascript `for on select ? i am new in PHP, have to learn a lot from `stackflow`

Comment: @KritikaGupta: i have updated my answer again. I expect that you learn some googling too dear...

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in Jquery itself.. What you have to do is,

```
$("#sp").change(function() {

   // get the word count field  value;

   // split the values by using  " " character and store it into an array

   // loop the array [ inside the loop do your calculation according to the selection of the choice ]


   // display the final value in the price field..
});
```

There are the steps to achieve it.